# Android - Horizontal Scrolling Views Inside Vertically Scrolling View

Tags: android, android-listview, horizontal-scrolling, android-scrollview, vertical-scrolling

On the Android, I would like to implement the following type of scrolling grid of thumbnails.

Top two rows scrolls horizontally... and, the whole page including the top two rows scrolls vertically.

Both of the horizontal rows will dynamically load additional images as they are scrolled horizontally... Also, the grid will dynamically load as it is scrolled vertically. (total number of items unknown ahead of time)

The issues I am concerned about are:

1. That horizontal swiping and vertical swiping will both work together nicely.
2. That view recycling will work for all sets of scrolling views.
3. Even if there were, say, 8 horizontal rows such that the bottom grid wasn't initially visible that it would still be able to be scrolled vertically.
4. What type of views would you recommend for each of the parts of this screen (e.g. ListView, ScrollView, etc...)?
5. What issues might I need to deal with (e.g. passing swipes up to parent views, etc...)?

Thank you... just getting starting on my Android coding adventures!

[image: sample grid view]
<sub>(source: [brianrice.com](http://www.brianrice.com/downloads/sample2.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for your first two views I would recommend you using `HorizontalListView`, then for other items, if they are always 6 squares in a row, create some simple `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation and 6 inner views. As for the whole layout use ordinary `ListView`.

There are really nothing special in using `HorizontalListView` inside `ListView` because they scroll on different axis, however in your adapter you would have to implement `getItemViewType(int position)` and `getViewTypeCount()`, because you have two different types of views in your layout, using this methods android knows what kind of views to supply for reuse in your `convertView` in `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`.
And using this mechanism - view recycling would work perfectly, because it would create at most 2 `HorizontalListView` and about 8 other view items.

Comment: The problem I am having is that the HorizontalListView seems to be stealing the vertical swipes from the ListView... and in the case where I have a screen full of HorizontalListViews I can't get it to scroll vertically... is there a way to get the HorizontalListViews to pass the vertical swipes up to it's parent?

Comment: Also, I believe, a HorizontalListView doesn't have an adapter for view recycling... so I need to use a Gallery???

Comment: Well, yes, I just remembered that when I had a combination of HorizontalScrollView and ordinary views I scrolled ListView using ordinary views and yes HorizontalScrollView is stealing touches. 
You can try then to customize a bit HorizontalScrollView and override onTouch event to make it always return false, this way you would also propagate touches to ListView.

Comment: And now about view recycling, yes, you are right it doesn't recycle views and you could use Gallery, but this is a deprecated API, so you should ask yourself a question if there are really so much items in one row that you need horizontal recycling?

Comment: ok, I tested returning false from onTouch and it won't help :) so there should be something else.

Comment: What I can suggest is to try redirecting all calls from HorizontallScrollView to ListView also.

Answer (score 5):

**What your long story means is simply:
*Horizontal RecyclerView in Vertical RecyclerView - Like the new google play layout***

follow these steps

## Step: 1

Create two Model Classes like below.

SingleItemModel.java

```
package com.pratap.gplaystore.models;


public class SingleItemModel {


    private String name;
    private String url;
    private String description;


    public SingleItemModel() {
    }

    public SingleItemModel(String name, String url) {
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
    }


    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


}
```

SectionDataModel.java

```
package com.pratap.gplaystore.models;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class SectionDataModel {



    private String headerTitle;
    private ArrayList<SingleItemModel> allItemsInSection;


    public SectionDataModel() {

    }
    public SectionDataModel(String headerTitle, ArrayList<SingleItemModel> allItemsInSection) {
        this.headerTitle = headerTitle;
        this.allItemsInSection = allItemsInSection;
    }



    public String getHeaderTitle() {
        return headerTitle;
    }

    public void setHeaderTitle(String headerTitle) {
        this.headerTitle = headerTitle;
    }

    public ArrayList<SingleItemModel> getAllItemsInSection() {
        return allItemsInSection;
    }

    public void setAllItemsInSection(ArrayList<SingleItemModel> allItemsInSection) {
        this.allItemsInSection = allItemsInSection;
    }


}
```

## Step: 2

Create an Activity with RecyclerView to show the list in vertical order.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.pratap.gplaystore;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.pratap.gplaystore.adapters.RecyclerViewDataAdapter;
import com.pratap.gplaystore.models.SectionDataModel;
import com.pratap.gplaystore.models.SingleItemModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;


    ArrayList<SectionDataModel> allSampleData;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        allSampleData = new ArrayList<SectionDataModel>();

        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            toolbar.setTitle("G PlayStore");

        }


        createDummyData();


        RecyclerView my_recycler_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        my_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);

        RecyclerViewDataAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewDataAdapter(this, allSampleData);

        my_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        my_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    public void createDummyData() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            SectionDataModel dm = new SectionDataModel();

            dm.setHeaderTitle("Section " + i);

            ArrayList<SingleItemModel> singleItem = new ArrayList<SingleItemModel>();
            for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
                singleItem.add(new SingleItemModel("Item " + j, "URL " + j));
            }

            dm.setAllItemsInSection(singleItem);

            allSampleData.add(dm);

        }
    }
}
```

Create an XML Layout for the above activity class

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" />


</LinearLayout>
```

## Step: 3

Now Create an Adapter Class for the recyclerView in the MainActivity.

RecyclerViewDataAdapter.java

```
package com.pratap.gplaystore.adapters;

/**
 * Created by pratap.kesaboyina on 24-12-2014.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.pratap.gplaystore.R;
import com.pratap.gplaystore.models.SectionDataModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDataAdapter.ItemRowHolder> {

    private ArrayList<SectionDataModel> dataList;
    private Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SectionDataModel> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        ItemRowHolder mh = new ItemRowHolder(v);
        return mh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemRowHolder itemRowHolder, int i) {

        final String sectionName = dataList.get(i).getHeaderTitle();

        ArrayList singleSectionItems = dataList.get(i).getAllItemsInSection();

        itemRowHolder.itemTitle.setText(sectionName);

        SectionListDataAdapter itemListDataAdapter = new SectionListDataAdapter(mContext, singleSectionItems);

        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);


        itemRowHolder.btnMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "click event on more, "+sectionName , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }
        });


       /* Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .centerCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.bg)
                .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != dataList ? dataList.size() : 0);
    }

    public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView itemTitle;

        protected RecyclerView recycler_view_list;

        protected Button btnMore;



        public ItemRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            this.itemTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
            this.recycler_view_list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_list);
            this.btnMore= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnMore);


        }

    }

}
```

Now create an xml Layout file for the above adapter class.

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnMore"
            android:text="Sample title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:theme="@style/MyButton"
            android:text="more"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

## Step: 4

Now , In order to make a horizontal RecyclerView , we need create a layout and Adapter class for each row.

list_single_card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/itemImage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/android" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/itemImage"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Sample title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The Adapter Class for Horizontal RecyclerView

SectionListDataAdapter.java

```
package com.pratap.gplaystore.adapters;

/**
 * Created by pratap.kesaboyina on 24-12-2014.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.pratap.gplaystore.R;
import com.pratap.gplaystore.models.SingleItemModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SectionListDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SectionListDataAdapter.SingleItemRowHolder> {

    private ArrayList<SingleItemModel> itemsList;
    private Context mContext;

    public SectionListDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SingleItemModel> itemsList) {
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public SingleItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_single_card, null);
        SingleItemRowHolder mh = new SingleItemRowHolder(v);
        return mh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int i) {

        SingleItemModel singleItem = itemsList.get(i);

        holder.tvTitle.setText(singleItem.getName());


       /* Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .centerCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.bg)
                .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != itemsList ? itemsList.size() : 0);
    }

    public class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView tvTitle;

        protected ImageView itemImage;


        public SingleItemRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            this.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            this.itemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);


            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), tvTitle.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });


        }

    }

}
```

Thats all folks!

http://android-pratap.blogspot.com.ng/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html

Comment: Hi, what if i want the entire recyclerview has horizontal scroll and vertical rows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675989/horizontal-and-vertical-scroll-in-recyclerview

Comment: I don't think that would work as expected (except am not getting your question) and even if it does its not a good design layout, because the main essence of recyclerview is now conquered. What you are trying to implement is a grid view inside recyclerview, if you ask me that's kinna messed-up.

Comment: How can i get position of 3rd item in second row?

Comment: play around with this logic in MainActivity (createDummyData() function). If i = 2 that's for second row and j = 2 that's for the third item. Together that's the 3rd item in second row.